# feeding a dataframe created from a CSV to MLlib Kmeans: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: csv, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

because i can not use spark csv i have manually created a dataframe from CSV as follow:

```
raw_data=sc.textFile("data/ALS.csv").cache()
csv_data=raw_data.map(lambda l:l.split(","))
header=csv_data.first()
csv_data=csv_data.filter(lambda line:line !=header)

row_data=csv_data.map(lambda p :Row (
location_history_id=p[0],
user_id=p[1],
latitude=p[2],
longitude=p[3],
address=p[4],
created_at=p[5],
valid_until=p[6],
timezone_offset_secs=p[7],
opening_times_id=p[8],
timezone_id=p[9]))

location_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_data)
location_df.registerTempTable("locations")
```

i need only two columns :

```
lati_longi_df=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT latitude, longitude FROM locations""")

rdd_lati_longi = lati_longi_df.map(lambda data: Vectors.dense([float(c) for c in data]))
rdd_lati_longi.take(2):
```

[DenseVector([-6.2416, 106.7949]),
 DenseVector([-6.2443, 106.7956])]

now it seems that every thing is ready for KMeans training:

```
    clusters = KMeans.train(rdd_lati_longi, 10, maxIterations=30,
    runs=10, initializationMode="random")
```

but i get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

First three lines of ALS.csv:
      location_history_id,user_id,latitude,longitude,address,created_at,valid_until,timezone_offset_secs,opening_times_id,timezone_id

Comment: @eliasah  i appreciate your help

Comment: @zero323 i would appreciate your help

Comment: You should provide some sample data from ALS.csv (should be easy to copy/paste) so that we can reproduce your code and hopefully your error.

Comment: @KatyaHandler i edited the question you can find the first three line and header

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem given those three lines. Out of curiosity, what happens if you run the following: `csv_data.map(lambda x: len(x)).distinct().collect()`? I wonder if somewhere in your underlying dataset is an empty line or perhaps a truncated row, that left you with an uneven number of columns per row.

Comment: @KatyaHandler i get this : [6, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 1, 11, 5, 13, 15]

Comment: That means that you have rows of all those lengths! Your underlying data is very messy. You're getting an `IndexError` because you have a rows of length less than 10, so when it tries to create `Row(p[0], ..., p[10])`, it can't find `p[10]` because the row is only of length 6 or 1 or 5!

Comment: @KatyaHandler thank you, is there a way to get rid of this? as i need only p[2] and p[3] .

Comment: That's a very complicated question, one not quite answererable here. You have messy underlying data. Try to figure out how many rows are the wrong length, and see if you can just throw them out. (If you have 1 billion rows of length 10 and 50 rows of another length, probably fine to toss them). Are you wrongly parsing strings that have commas within them? Esp with something like addresses, you may have commas within your field (e.g. "123 Main Street, New York, New York 10001") that are throwing off your `split(",")`. You have to look in depth at your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you allow spark to parse csv instead? You can enable csv support with something like this:

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```